# Ranking based off conditional field

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql

I am looking to select only 1 row based off the IMMS_ID field. Which row I select is based off this if statement (excuse the syntax)

`if (status group based off IMMS_ID) status='DI' select the DI row
else if ... status='OI' ...
else if ... status='FI' ...
else if ... status='OV' ...
else if ... status='FV' ...`

So this means if the group based off the IMMS_ID contains OI, OV and FV I want to select the row that has OI (as it's highest in the if/elseif statement).

Ex. Here is a dataset

`ID  IMMS_ID  STATUS
 1      1       FV 
 2      1       OI 
 3      1       FI 
 4      2       DI 
 5      2       OV`

So for this dataset I'd want the following results returned

`ID  IMMS_ID  STATUS
 2      1       OI 
 4      2       DI`

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate a RANK/ROW_NUMBER based on this logic:

```
ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (PARTITION BY IMMS_ID 
      ORDER BY CASE WHEN status='DI' THEN 1
                    WHEN status='OI' THEN 2
                    WHEN status='FI' THEN 3
                    WHEN status='OV' THEN 4
                    WHEN status='FV' THEN 5
                END)
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you. It was almost 5pm and my brain was mush :^)